# IDEA Module generation in Jenkins

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jenkins, gradle

I am currently trying to set up offline inspections in Jenkins, but I keep getting the error that there are no modules in my project:

`This project contains no modules. Inspection cannot proceed.`

I saw this earlier [Run Inspections offline (from Jenkins) Android Studio 1.1 vs 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633883/run-inspections-offline-from-jenkins-android-studio-1-1-vs-1-5) and also that there is a new idea gradle plugin that generates module information. Can we use this plugin then to generate everything we need for offline IDEA inspections, or is there something else missing?

Comment: How do you call the inspection? Please add your script.

Comment: I am currently running it from the [idea-cli-inspector](https://github.com/bentolor/idea-cli-inspector) github project. I am pretty sure it is a local environment issue, but I can't figure it out. I have also come across the error "Please specify the module `onlyModule` with api level 23."